# Processus command powershell don't kill Rundeck

Tags: powershell, rundeck

I'm using rundeck since 2 years. When I launch my job using powershell command on remote host connecting in WINRM, the processus in my Windows continue to running when I kill job in rundeck.

Do you have an solution for that? I'm using rundeck 2.11.11-1.

King regards,
Francis

Comment: Do you see any clue at `service.log` file? (`/var/log/rundeck/service.log`). Could you try with the latest rundeck version? (on a test environment).

Answer (score 0):

Since Rundeck 2.11 a lot of bug-fixes are added, even those related to your issue, e.g: [this one](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/pull/4432) applied on Rundeck 3.0.14.

Quick solution, move to [latest](https://docs.rundeck.com/downloads.html) Rundeck version (3.3.10 right now) and use [pywinrm plugin](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/py-winrm-plugin) (out of the box with current Rundeck version) instead of old (and unmaintained) [overthere winrm plugin](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/rundeck-winrm-plugin).